# script to document.write array minus variable name but with individualized text before each value (help! :)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to write a script that will document.write the variable information from an array (out of a form) but a) without the variable name = (figured that part out, see below) and b) instead put individualized text in front of each value (e.g. You pledged $ (value they entered), Your name is (value they entered) etc.  It is the b) part that has me bashing my head against a wall. With just the values printing it is a lot better than "myfunkyvariablename=value" but just having the value coming out doesn't tell the person who entered the data all the information that they need.  Is there a way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var formData = location.search;
formData = formData.substring(1, formData.length);
while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
}
formData = unescape(formData);
var formArray = formData.split("&");
for (var i=0; i < formArray.length; ++i) {
var printBegin=formArray[i].search("=") +1 
document.write(formArray[i].substring(printBegin) + "<br />");
}

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Any help on this would be seriously appreciated.

Comment: Off topic, but `unescape` is deprecated.. use  `decodeURI()` or `decodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Thank you for the heads up on that Callback.  I've just finished a beginner's javascript course (it covered the 1st five chapters of the Javascript book by Gosselin) and so hadn't heard of the decodeURI() etc functions but am now going to look them up and try to use one of those instead of the unescape.  Trying to learn as much as I can sans class now :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution but it will only work if you know all the elements in the form.  The code above works great to strip off the unwanted variable names from the form array.  What you do next is to create a second array with corresponding elements to the form elements and with values that say what you want to output.  Then you put the two arrays into a table like this:

```
document.write("<table>")

                        var formData = location.search;
                        formData = formData.substring(1, formData.length);
                        while (formData.indexOf("+") != -1) {
                            formData = formData.replace("+", " ");
                        }
                        formData = unescape(formData);
                        var formArray = formData.split("&");


                        for (var i=0; i < formArray.length; ++i) {
            var printBegin=formArray[i].search("=") +1; 

            document.write("<tr><td>" + responseArray[i] + "</td><td>" + formArray[i].substring(printBegin) +  "</td></tr>");

                        }
                         document.write("</table>");
```